# Use DictField in combined model serializer in Django DRF

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

**Environment**:

```
Django 2.2.16
Django RESTFramework 3.8.2
```

Let's say, I wan to group my query_set to a specific format and serializer all models at a time.

In the past, we used a customized model to grouping the type and then feed to the customize serializer.
However, we recently trying to upgrade the Django from 1.11.x to 2.2 and so as DRF.

Then, there's an error prompt and I can't fix it. I also find a [link](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/issues/5384), Look like it's a known issue in DRF.

**AttributeError: 'DictField' object has no attribute 'partial'**

I defined several models and serializer.

```
class ModelA(models.Model):
    job_id = models.IntegerField()
    type = models.CharField(max_length=16)
    ... Some fields

class ModelASerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer)
    class Meta:
        model = ModelA
        field = '__all__'

class ModelB(models.Model):
    Job_id = models.IntegerField()
    type = models.CharField(max_length=16)
    ... Some fields

class ModelBSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer)
    class Meta:
        model = ModelB
        field = '__all__'

... and many models below
```

I create a customized model to serialize all models to specific format.

```
class CustomizeModel:
   def __init__(self, Job_id):
     self.a = {}
     self.b = {}

   # In below, I group the query_set by 'type'
   a_set = ModelA.objects.filter(job_id=job_id)
   for obj in a_set:
      if obj.type not in self.a: 
         self.a[obj.type] = []
      self.a[obj.type].append(obj)

   b_set = ModelB.objects.filter(job_id=job_id)
   for obj in a_set:
      if obj.type not in self.b: 
         self.b[obj.type] = []
      self.b[obj.type].append(obj)
       

class CustomizeSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    a = serializers.DictField(child=ModelASerializer(many=True))
    b = serializers.DictField(child=ModelBSerializer(many=True))
```

My view:

```
def get_model_data(request, job_id):
    ...

    model = CustomizeModel(job_id)
    serializer = CustomizeSerializer(model)

    # This serialize.data gives an error
    # AttributeError: 'DictField' object has no attribute 'partial'
    json_str = json.dumps(serializer.data)

    return HttpResponse(json_str)
```

The code is worked in Django 1.11 and DRF 3.5.4

My expected result is to dump to the JSON format like below

```
{ 
  a: {type1: [query_set_a filter by job_id and type1],
      type2: [query_set_a filter by job_id and type2]},
  b: {type1: [query_set_b filter by job_id and type1],
      type2: [query_set_b filter by job_id and type2]}, 
}
```

However, I tried several ways to rewrite this serializer but got no luck.

```
class CustomizeModel:
   def __init__(self, Job_id):
     self.a = ModelA.objects.filter(job_id=job_id)
     self.b = ModelB.objects.filter(job_id=job_id)

class CustomizeSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    a = ModelASerializer(many=True)
    b = ModelBSerializer(many=True)
```

It worked. But I don't have a good approach to **group_by('type')** to my expected format after CustomizeSerializer.

**How do I rewrite the DictField in CustomizeSerializer in Django2.2?**